# Mesh face missing after importing from blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So I modelled a gun model for my game in blender, and after importing it in Unity one of the faces simply disappeared as you can see in the link below :

https://ibb.co/rwPDY8r

I tried flipping the normal on that face in blender, recalculate the normals, and half a dozen of other solution for that problem I found online, but nothing works.

it's weird because it does appear normal in Blender :

https://ibb.co/BVdMGqg

One thing I noticed is that when I open the .fbx file with windows 3D viewer, this anomaly is visible on the hidden face :

https://ibb.co/1ZLxf0D

It is the only face on the model that has that black anomaly, all the others are normal.

I am about to give up and just delete it and start over. So if anyone has a solution I would be very grateful since I already spent a few hours making the gun and a couple more trying to fix this, I would hate to have to redo everything again (Especially since i'm pretty proud of that gun).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Ok so nothing worked. I tried all the answers here (which I did try before but tried them again just in case) and it's still not working. I Even tried duplicating the face and extruding it a bit, still invisible. I'll scrap this one and make another, this time with backface culling enabled so I can see what I can do. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an inverted face in your mesh. Here is how to find that:

[image]

You can select it and choose "flip normal" in edit mode. Or just choose "recalculate outside" with all faces selected.

[image]

As an alternative to "Face Orientation", you could enable "Backface Culling" which is what Unity does by default (unless you enable the material to be "double sided" or play with the Cull type in shader.)

This will hide the problematic face as you are looking against the backside. Fly inside the mesh and you will see the other side being rendered.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved in four simple steps:

1. Click model on blender
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Edit Mode
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to Recalculates Normals.
4. Save, Export from blender and going to unity again will fix.

Answer (score 0):

When you import .fbx to Unity you can also change the Normals method import to calculate in import settings. Sometimes it helps.